# How can I add Amarok to the launcher?

Tags: unity, amarok

When I try to drag the Amarok icon from the dash into the launcher, the icon just disappears. How do I get it to stay?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

launch Amarok from the dash and then right click the icon that appears on the launcher and select "Keep in Launcher"